# how to make flutter app support for chrome OS

Tags: android, ios, flutter, google-chrome-os, chromebook

Currently having a flutter app with android And IOS support, how to make this app support for chrome book OS also. Already its working fine with responsive screen but the issues is the app is flickers in so many places.